# Where do I drop off and pick up a foot passenger in Calais (P&O)?

Tags: france, ferries

I'm dropping off and later picking up a foot passenger in Calais next week. I know how to drive to the ships if I'm boarding by car, but I am not coming with. Where can I get closest the foot passenger terminal by car? What signs should I follow? Is there an address I can put in my navigation?

I did find this website: http://www.calais-cotedopale.co.uk/practical/port-calais/calais-ferry-terminal which refers to http://www.portboulognecalais.fr/ferries-passagers/services-aux-voyageurs/parking/, but doesn't exit (404). Is that parking spot still there?

Comment: Note: the great instructions in the accepted answer might also be valid for *picking up arriving foot passengers*, too, according to [this page](https://www.portboulognecalais.fr/en/preparing-your-calais-douvres-crossing): "P5 – Drop-off and short-stay car park - PAYING: 
* Direct access to the entrance of the Arrivals/Departures terminal
* The first 30 minutes are free
* Car park is enclosed and guarded". 
If that's indeed true, the question could cover twice as much ground if extended to "drop off/pick up foot passengers...".

Comment: @Sz. That is true. I'll edit it in, since it is correct.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Drive up to the port as you normally would, but instead of driving into ticketing and passport control, follow the signs for parking: turn right and go around the [roundabout](https://goo.gl/maps/iMpYJcbw5xR2) to the parking/ticket office area. There are signs for this when you come off the motorway. Drive all the way to the [passenger terminal at the end](https://goo.gl/maps/QBDzv7XNzuE2), where you can [park in lot P5 for free](http://www.portboulognecalais.fr/en/preparing-your-calais-douvres-crossing) for up to 30 minutes and drop off your passenger.

Comment: After some more rooting around on Google maps I managed to decipher the text on the blue signs in the lot (with white arrows pointing to the ferry).  They say "foot passengers," and the lighter-blue circle is a standard "pedestrian zone" sign.  You can almost make it out here: https://www.google.com/maps/@50.9674973,1.867739,3a,15y,214.01h,86.31t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1saLaG7_wjDBV5W88JiRsjQA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Comment: Managed to find it quite easily. Except I never took that roundabout, as I came from the east. You just follow the signs for 'car ferry' (a bit confusing, but it's what you do, don't follow the truck ones). Then the signs for 'no reservation/tickets' as you said, and you'll find lots of parking spots. All of it is free. There are 3 parking zones, shorter times are closer to the building. 30 minutes, 2 hours and unlimited.

Comment: That same P5 parking lot also seems to be the place for *picking up* arriving passengers. (https://www.portboulognecalais.fr/en/preparing-your-calais-douvres-crossing)

Answer (score 4):

The place indicated in the link below is not the closest you can get without taking your car on the ferry.  It seems to be the pedestrian entrance for those who are not arriving at the ferry by car.  Google Maps indicates a bus stop nearby, but I see no evidence of that in street view:

https://www.google.com/maps/@50.9649129,1.8619856,3a,75y,347.21h,84.34t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sfvnFZO7y3DZp-wWjJ2wbkA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Furthermore, this spot doesn't have a good place for a car to stop, so you're better off following the directions in Michael Hampton's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/82137/19400).

Comment: The Google orthophotos look like that entrance leads up the ramp towards the same building that the OP is pointing to. It seems to be for passengers arriving _by foot_ from the city center. For dropping off, it looks like one gets to the airport-style drop-off forecourt to the east of the terminal by following the signs towards "TICKET OFFICE" from the autoroute.